# Не работает IF для GET запроса

Tags: java

Нужна срочная помощь.

```
public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) throws Exception {
      URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      return rd.readLine();
}
```

Этот код я использую, чтобы получить данные по ссылке подобным образом:

```
String test = getHTML("http://site.ru/test?" + anystring);
```

Но когда я пытаюсь сделать if, например
if (test == "01"), то ничего не происходит. Помогите новичку пожалуйста!

Comment: Наверное вы строки не так сравниваете. В яве надо через `equals`, т.е. `if (test.equals("01"))`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Обязательно попробую такой способ. Я просто новичок

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!